# why is a sony .mts file so large?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, multimedia

I don't know much about multimedia knowledge. I know sony **.mts** file is a type of H.264 container. I use **ffmpeg** to dump my **.mts** file into a **.mpeg** file. Except the **.mpeg** file is shrunk around **5** times smaller in size than **.mts**, the **ffmpeg** dump information on both files is identical. I am confusing why **.mts** files have large size. What important features are lost by my conversion?

Thanks!

Kejia

---

Thanks to all answers.

I checked the output of both again and found that there is one different place: **bitrate**. Then I definitely lost quality. Now I adjust the bit rate in terms of the expectation to displaying equipment---yes, considering **displaying equipments** is necessary (an expert's advice):    `$ ffmpeg -b 9498k -i my.mts my.mpg`. Another interesting option is **-ab**, **audio bit rate**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MTS files typically come from high-definition camcorders. They use the AVCHD coded which uses MPEG-4 AVC/H.264 video encoding and Dolby AC-3 (Dolby Digital) or uncompressed linear PCM audio coding. Are you sure that you are not decreasing the quality or resolution?

Comment: Maybe, there is some default *compression* options. My operation is simple:    `$ ffmpeg -i my.mts my.mpeg`

Answer (score 1):

Your file has H.264/MPEG-4 AVC video compression and Dolby Digital (AC-3) audio compression or uncompressed LPCM audio, so this equals to a fairly large source file size.

When you export (convert) to MPG, you most likely perform a lossy compression. Please double check, especially the audio track.

Comment: I don't think the uncompressed LPCM audio is very common.